# Do goroutines keep running even if main function is terminated?

Tags: multithreading, go, goroutine

I am running a server where main fires off several go routines. like this:

```
main() {
     go someFn(){
       // will run for infinite time()
     }
     go otherFn()
}
```

I have two doubts:

1. what if the main function is exited? will these threads will still run or will terminate with the main function?
2. if no, then what is the best method to make the main function run forever/ or run till I need it? currently, I am using `select{}` command for making it run forever! is there any better and more efficient method available than `select{}`

Comment: Please read [A Tour of Go](https://tour.golang.org/) for basic concepts like this. Specifically, the section on [concurrency](https://tour.golang.org/concurrency/1).

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I would recommend to read [the language specification](https://golang.org/ref/spec) in its entirety — Go is one of a very small number of laguages whose language spec can really be read over two lunches (or a single one — if this is your, I dunno, third of fourth programming language).

To cite [it](https://golang.org/ref/spec#Program_execution):

> Program execution begins by initializing the `main` package and then invoking the function `main`. When that function invocation returns, the program exits. It does not wait for other (non-main) goroutines to complete.

---

I would add that logically making `main` wait all non-main goroutines would be a bad thing for two reasons:

1. That would easily create situations where you could wait for a program to shut down for some indeterminate amount of time *even if you do not want that* (and you not always want that).

   Logically, that would require inventing a "special" way to end `main` — something like [`abort(3)` from C](https://manpages.debian.org/3/abort), and having such a way is a sure path for it to be abused.
2. Any sensible usage of goroutines where you actually *need* to wait on them anyway requires explicit synchronisation — just per the language specification and its [memory model](https://golang.org/ref/mem).
   That is, when you want to wait on outstanding goroutines, you must do that explicitly.

Answer (score 1):

The program exits when the function `main()` returns.

If one of `someFn` or `otherFn` runs forever, then call that function directly at the end of `main`.  The `main` function never exits with this change.

If neither function runs forever, the use a [sync.WaitGroup](https://godoc.org/sync#WaitGroup) to wait on the goroutines and then exit.

The empty select statement `select {}` efficiently blocks a goroutine forever.

Answer (score 1):

> [Do] go routines keeps on running even if main function is terminated?

No.

This is asked once a week.

Comment: It is very common to find the same question from different people across time. Downvoting as I think this short answer could be a comment and also "This is asked once a week" is not part of the asnwer. You may mark it as a duplicate in any case. I mean Volker, how do you feel if someone tolds that your question is beign asked every time? I mean... that is not the concern for the one who ask. I see you got a point, but again, you may mark this question as duplicated an offer a link to an accepted common answer.

Answer (score 1):

In my opinion, when it is difficult to remember a concept the best thing is to code such concept yourself.

Here is a simple program which demonstrates that go routines are terminated when main function exits:

```
package main

import (
    "log"
    "os"
    "time"
)

func main() {
    f, err := os.Create("./test.txt")
    if err != nil {
        log.Fatal("can not write to a file", err)
    }
    go func() {
        for {
            f.WriteString("new line created at: " + time.Now().String() + "\n")
            time.Sleep(1 * time.Second)
        }
    }()
    time.Sleep(5 * time.Second)
    // writing to the file by goroutine will be finished in 5 seconds
    // when main exits
}
```